# Forge viewer call focus method

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

In forge viewer I want to call the focus method from my script to focus on selected elements.

[image: like this image]

I cannot find method like

```
viewer.focuse(viewer.getSelection());
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. You should add code or images directly, since link-addresses can change. It also makes it easier for the SO community to reproduce your query. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple, just call `Viewer3D#fitToView()`~

```
var selection = viewer.getSelection();
viewer.fitToView( selection );
```

See here for the documentation:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/